# Draw stops working after if

Tags: java, draw, maze

I'm trying to create a maze with Union Find, but am unable to remove walls.
This is what I have got so far.

```
 private void createMaze (int cells, Graphics g) {
     s = new int[cells*cells]; //No unions yet setting all to -1
     for(int i = 0; i < cells*cells; ++i){
         s[i] = -1;
     }
     g.setColor(Color.yellow);
     random = new Random();

     while(breaker){
         g.setColor(Color.yellow);
         int innerWall = random.nextInt(4)+0;
         int randomCellX = random.nextInt(cells-1)+0;
         int randomCellY = random.nextInt(cells)+0;

         if(randomCellX==cells&&innerWall==2||
            randomCellX==0&&innerWall==0||
            randomCellY==cells-1&&innerWall==3||
            randomCellY==0&&innerWall==1){
             continue; 
         }           
         else{

             int location = randomCellX+(randomCellY*cells);
             int neighbour = 0;
             if(innerWall==0){
                 neighbour =location-1;
             }
             else if(innerWall==1){
                 neighbour =location-cells;
             }
             else if(innerWall==2){
                 neighbour =location+1;
             }
             else if(innerWall==3){
                 neighbour =location+cells;
             }
             int locationRoot =find(location);
             int neighbourRoot =find(neighbour);

             if(locationRoot==neighbourRoot){
                 breaker = checkIfDone(s);
                }
             union(location,neighbour);
             drawWall(randomCellX,randomCellY,innerWall,g);


         }


     }
}
```

If I remove the

```
if(randomCellX==cells&&innerWall==2||
            randomCellX==0&&innerWall==0||
            randomCellY==cells-1&&innerWall==3||
            randomCellY==0&&innerWall==1){
             continue; 
         }
```

It removes the lines fine,but when it is added the walls are not removed. The method is called but doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems some logical mistake have been done obviously. But can not spot specifically as you haven't given the explanation of the logic you have done. Only can help showing the path where the problem might be happening.

Since you can not reach the `else` block anyway, it is obvious that one or more of these conditions in `if` are **always** `true`.

```
(randomCellX == cells && innerWall == 2)
(randomCellX == 0 && innerWall == 0)
(randomCellY == cells - 1 && innerWall == 3)
(randomCellY == 0 && innerWall == 1)
```

That's why you are getting true for the if condition and continuing the loop without doing anything. Ensure the conditions are okay.

If these conditions are right, the next suspect might be these lines:

```
 int innerWall = random.nextInt(4)+0;
 int randomCellX = random.nextInt(cells-1)+0;
 int randomCellY = random.nextInt(cells)+0;
```

Check whether these random values range are exactly what you want or not. For example: you are taking random values for `randomCellX` from 0 to cells-2, but for `randomCellY` the range is 0 to cells-1.